# Having trouble with importing data from a file. I am getting an endless loop

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ifstream

I can get my file to load 1 full struct. But when I try to iterate through the file, i have an endless loop and no data is loaded. I have attached my code and the flat file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct video_items{
    string Title;
    int YOP;
    string Category;
    float Gross;
}video;

void LoadMovies (vector<video> &v);
void SearchMovies (vector <video> &v, string s);

int main()
{
    vector <video> v;

    LoadMovies(v);

    cout<<"Total number of movies: "<<v.size()<<endl;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<v[i].Title<<endl;
        cout<<"Category: "<<v[i].Category<<endl;
        cout<<"Year of Publication: "<<v[i].YOP<<endl;
        cout<<"Gross: "<<v[i].Gross<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------"<<endl<<endl;
    }

    string WantMovie;
    cout<<"Please type in what movie you want."<<endl;
    cin>>WantMovie;
    SearchMovies(v,WantMovie);

    return 0;
}

void LoadMovies (vector<video> &v)
{
    video L;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("Movies.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout <<"Loading Movie Catalog..."<<endl<<endl;
        int i=0;
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            myfile.ignore();
            //cout<<i<<endl<<endl;

            v.push_back(L);
            getline(myfile,v[i].Title);
            getline(myfile,v[i].Category);
            myfile>>v[i].YOP;
            myfile>>v[i].Gross;
            i++;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout<<"Unable to open file."<<endl;
}

void SearchMovies (vector <video> &v, string s)
{
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    unsigned int i;

    for (i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i].Title.compare(0,s.size(),s)==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i >=v.size()){
        i =0;
    }
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:cout<<"You have chosen "<<s<<endl;
        break;
        default:
        cout<<"That movie is not currently in the library, please choose a different one."<<endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

First character ignored in flat file.

=========Data File==========

```
 Captain America: The First Avenger
Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
2011
1786.65
Iron Man
Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
2008
585.2
The Incredible Hulk
Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
2008
134.52
Iron Man 2
Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
2010
312.43
Thor
Action, Adventure, Fantasy
2011
181.03
The Avengers
Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
2012
623.28
Iron Man 3
Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
2013
409.01
```

Comment: And when you ran your program in your debugger, what observations did you make? This is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your programs one line at a time, inspect all variables and their values as they change, and analyze your programs' logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find the bug in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck, then think about what you have to accomplish to read each struct from your datafile. You need to read 4 pieces of information, 2-strings, 1-int, 1-float. You are thinking correctly to read into a temporary struct `L`, but what you want to do is validate you have correctly filled all four members of `L` before adding `L` to your vector.

To accomplish a successful read of all four members, you must first read the first-member. Condition your read-loop on reading the first member, e.g.:

```
    while (getline (myfile, L.Title)) {         /* validate each read */
```

After having read the first member, validate each of the next three members being read:

```
        if (getline (myfile, L.Category) &&
            myfile >> L.YOP && myfile >> L.Gross) {
            v.push_back(L);     /* before adding temp struct to vector */
            i++;
        }
```

It's risky to presume you only have a single `'\n'` following `Gross` in your input file and makes your read fragile. Ignore all characters to end of line, e.g.

```
        /* ignore all characters to \n */
        myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Do not use *Magic Numbers* or *Hardcode Filenames* in your code. `main()` takes arguments which allows you to pass a filename to read data from on the command line (or you can take it as input), but don't bury a hardcoded filename down in a funciton:

```
    myfile.open ("Movies.txt");
```

Instead, pass the filename on the command line, e.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {  /* validate at least 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    LoadMovies(v, argv[1]);   /* pass filename to open to LoadMovies */
```

There is no reason for six calls to `std::cout` to display each movie. One will do:

```
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------\n"
                  << v[i].Title << '\n'
                  << "Category: " << v[i].Category << '\n'
                  << "Year of Publication: " << v[i].YOP << '\n'
                  << "Gross: " << v[i].Gross << '\n'
                  << "----------------------------------------------------\n\n";
```

Have `SearchMovies()` provide a meaningful return to indicate success/failure back in the caller. You ideally want to separate your implementation (your logic/calculations) from your interface (your output to the user). If you provide a meaningful return type for `SearchMovies()` you can remove the output from the function completely and have that provided back in `main()` based upon your return. A simple return of type `int` is fine. `-1` to indicate not found in library, or return the index in your vector on success. Example:

```
int SearchMovies (std::vector<video>& v, const std::string& s)
{
    int i;
    std::string slower (s);                 /* string s to lowercase */
    std::transform (slower.begin(), slower.end(), 
                    slower.begin(), 
                    [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });


    for (i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); i++) {   /* movie title to lowercase */
        std::string mlower (v[i].Title);
        std::transform (mlower.begin(), mlower.end(), 
                        mlower.begin(), 
                        [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });

        if (mlower == slower)   /* compare lowercase movie and string */
            return i;
    }

    return -1;  /* if not found, return -1 (cannot be an index) */
}
```

(**note:** you can loop converting each character to lowercase, or you can just use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to convert all characters.)

By converting both the movie title as well as your `WantMovie` search string, you can make an comparison in your search function.

Then in `main()` you can simply output the movie title at that index within your vector `v`, e.g.

```
    std::cout << "Please type in what movie you want.\n";
    if (getline (std::cin, WantMovie)) {
        int index = SearchMovies (v, WantMovie);
        if (index != -1)    /* validate search and output here */
            std::cout << "You have chosen: " << v.at(index).Title << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << WantMovie << " is not currently in the library.\n";
    }
```

Your search will then work regardless of the case the user uses to type in the search term, e.g.

```
...
Please type in what movie you want.
iron man 3
You have chosen: Iron Man 3
```

or

```
...
Please type in what movie you want.
thor
You have chosen: Thor
```

That should get you pointed in the right direction. If you run into additional stumbling blocks, let me know and I'm happy to help further.